# PHP exec() and shell_exec() returning "The system cannot execute the specified program" when I try to run a python script from my code

Tags: php, windows, apache, shell, php-7

- I'm running Apache on a fresh install of XAMPP on a Windows 10
  device
- No modifications to php.ini or any other config file.
- The script works perfectly when I run it from BASH or CMD.
- The code can execute other commands such as "help", "echo hello" and
  "makedir funky_monkey".
- The script I'm trying to run is a python .py script that performs SSH operations, it runs on python 3.7 and the command to run it is:
- `python "F:\xampp\htdocs\...\SSHScript.py" -h`

Comment: Did you try `exec('c:\path\to\python "F:\xampp\htdocs\...\SSHScript.py" -h');`? If `F:` is a mapped drive does the Apache user have an F: drive mapped (probably not)?

Comment: Your Apache server - like most daemons (or "services" as they're called in Windows) - runs under a different account with a different (and usually very restricted) environment and permissions set. The fact you can run the script as yourself (with your own user account) doesn't mean that the Apache process can.  I don't know how to admin services environment / permissions on Windows (I don't use Windows), but this is certainly documented.

Comment: NB: removed the Python tag as it's totally irrelevant, and added the Windows one which is much more useful here.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried:  `exec('python "F:\xampp\htdocs\...\SSHScript.py" -h', $response, $return);`  the `$response` held the text I posted in the title and the `$return = 1`, I'm not sure if the Apache user had `F:` but I do know that copying the script to `C:` locations failed because it couldn't see it for come reason, how do I check if the Apache used has `F:`? I'm using XAMPP

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?